# How to groupby in an ordering manner than taking a different column on same rows with it?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

This is how I have data which has 1000000 columns. Below is a fraction of it. And I changed values of pred just for people to see easier.There are many users solving cards. about 16000 users and 16000 cards.

```
      user    card  true          pred
0      7933   4169   1.0  0.821682
1     16151   2940   1.0  0.724903
2     15134   2183   1.0  0.826126
3     12775   5977   1.0  0.685955
4       196  14972   1.0  0.719164
5     12994   8631   1.0  0.739311
6     15351   9968   1.0  0.738173
7      5413   7292   1.0  0.685801
8      8232   6662   1.0  0.764592
9     10437  12367   1.0  0.934161
```

```
user_pred = data.groupby(by = ['user'], as_index = False).apply(lambda x: x['pred'].sort_values(ascending= False))
```

And this returns me as below.
and I did this as below to get groups in order of pred. This is only the first user data (only user 0) as the group is big.

```
user    index      pred
0      5172761    0.934161
       2193689    0.826126
       544664     0.821682
       8472082    0.764592
       4678627    0.739311
       1742257    0.738173
       450349     0.724903
       6202140    0.719164
       8834527    0.685955
       6149264    0.685801
```

Which says, User 0 has preds and the result is ordered on pred.
But what I ultimately want is I want to get this with the associated true column. So the goal would look like this

```
user   index       pred      true
0      5172761    0.934161    1.0
       2193689    0.826126    1.0
       544664     0.821682    1.0
       8472082    0.764592    1.0
       4678627    0.739311    1.0
       1742257    0.738173    1.0
       450349     0.724903    1.0
       6202140    0.719164    1.0
       8834527    0.685955    1.0
       6149264    0.685801    1.0
```

Can someone provide a code for this? Thank you in advance.
Cheers.

Comment: your output is different from the shared data. Also your original data has no `userGUID`

Comment: good fix. another question. where is the index column from? cant find it in the original data

Comment: Index column just comes up when I do the code automatically.

Comment: I think you should run your code on the original data you shared. the index seems to be what you get when you run it on the entire data.

Comment: why not just use sort_values by user and pred desc? Do you have to group by user to do some agg job?